# Error when executing right to be forgotten in scheduled task

Tags: xconnect, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a Sitecore scheduled task to automatically ExecuteRightToBeForgotten for contacts that haven't had any interaction with the site for a number of days.

I can get the contacts I need, but after calling ExecuteRightToBeForgotten and Submitting the changes, an error is thrown:

```
ManagedPoolThread #5 11:51:03 INFO  Starting: ContactCleanup
ManagedPoolThread #5 11:51:03 INFO  Starting ContactCleanup task
ManagedPoolThread #5 11:51:07 ERROR Error executing command item: ContactCleanup
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem.Execute(Item[] items, ScheduleItem schedule)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Foundation.ContactCleanup.Tasks.ContactCleanupTask.CleanupContacts(Int32 days) in D:\projects\platform\src\Foundation\ContactCleanup\code\Foundation.ContactCleanup\Tasks\ContactCleanupTask.cs:line 53
   at Foundation.ContactCleanup.Tasks.ContactCleanupTask.Execute(Item[] items, CommandItem command, ScheduleItem schedule) in D:\projects\platform\src\Foundation\ContactCleanup\code\Foundation.ContactCleanup\Tasks\ContactCleanupTask.cs:line 24


ManagedPoolThread #5 11:51:07 ERROR Error executing schedule item: ContactCleanup
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem.Execute(Item[] items, ScheduleItem schedule)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.ScheduleItem.Execute()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Foundation.ContactCleanup.Tasks.ContactCleanupTask.CleanupContacts(Int32 days) in D:\projects\platform\src\Foundation\ContactCleanup\code\Foundation.ContactCleanup\Tasks\ContactCleanupTask.cs:line 53
   at Foundation.ContactCleanup.Tasks.ContactCleanupTask.Execute(Item[] items, CommandItem command, ScheduleItem schedule) in D:\projects\platform\src\Foundation\ContactCleanup\code\Foundation.ContactCleanup\Tasks\ContactCleanupTask.cs:line 24
```

My xDB is up and there are Contacts that are found to be forgotten (532 in total). Is this a thing with scheduled tasks not being able to edit contacts or something?

Here's the code that's being run by the scheduled task:

```
public class ContactCleanupTask 
{
    private const string CleanupAfterDays = "Foundation.ContactCleanup.CleanupAfterDays";

    public void Execute(Item[] items, Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem command, Sitecore.Tasks.ScheduleItem schedule)
    {
        Log.Info("Starting ContactCleanup task", this);

        if (!int.TryParse(Settings.GetSetting(CleanupAfterDays), out var days))
        {
            days = 420; // 14 months
        }
        var result = CleanupContacts(days);

        Log.Info($"ContactCleanup finished, executed right to be forgotten for {result} contacts.", this);
    }

    private int CleanupContacts(int days)
    {
        int numberOfForgottenContacts = 0;
        using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                // Query to find contacts without any interactions after set amount of days
                var query = client.Contacts
                    .Where(contact => !contact.Interactions.Any(interaction => interaction.EndDateTime > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-days)));

                // Execute query and extract contacts
                var contactCursor = query.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(50);

                while (contactCursor.MoveNext(50))
                {
                    var currentBatch = contactCursor.Current;

                    foreach (var contact in currentBatch)
                    {
                        numberOfForgottenContacts++;
                        client.ExecuteRightToBeForgotten(contact);
                    }

                }

                client.Submit();
            }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Xdb Error while processing contacts to forget", ex, this);
            }

            return numberOfForgottenContacts;
        }
    }
}
```

Note; the catch isn't hit because it's not an `xDbExecutionException`, but the `ContactCleanupTask.cs:line 53` from the log is the `client.Submit();` call

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known behavior of xConnect.

You can not use ExecuteRightToBeForgotteninside a batch enumerator.

Method ExecuteRightToBeForgotten looks like :

```
public static RightToBeForgottenOperation ExecuteRightToBeForgotten(this IXdbContext context, IEntityReference<Contact> contact)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    if (contact == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("contact");
    }
    RightToBeForgottenOperation rightToBeForgottenOperation = new RightToBeForgottenOperation(contact);
    context.RegisterOperation(rightToBeForgottenOperation);
    return rightToBeForgottenOperation;
}
```

in the     **context.RegisterOperation(rightToBeForgottenOperation)** you have :

```
public void RegisterOperation(IXdbOperation operation)
{
    if (!this.Configuration.IsDataExtractionEnabled && (operation is CreateContactCursorOperation || operation is CreateInteractionCursorOperation))
    {
        throw new XdbExecutionException("The data extraction is disabled for this client.");
    }
    this.CheckNotDisposed();
    if (this._executingBatchCount > 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Operations cannot be added to the context while it is executing. Add operations directly to the executing batch instead");
    }
    this.EnsureBatch();
    this._currentBatch.Add(operation, true);
}
```

If it's a batch operation InvalidOperationException is thrown . 
 You need to add your contacts to a list and you need to use ExecuteRightToBeForgotten one by one for every contact.

You need to be careful with the **WithExpandOptions** . You can use use the parameter less variant

Comment: Apart from caching the resulting Contacts in a List and putting `GetBatchEnumeratorSync` in a `using` block, I also needed to add `.WithExpandOptions(new ContactExpandOptions()` with some custom facet keys to make sure `ExecuteRightToBeForgotten` had access to them to make it work all the way, but your help was the breakthrough I needed!